# Overhead of threads on performance

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to increase the performance of an app by adding threads to do concurrent tasks. The results I've gotten are very confusing to me and make me think there is some kind of thread related overhead of which I am not aware. Below are two copies of the same code with the exception that one uses threads and the other doesn't. The one that doesn't use threads runs four times faster than the one that uses threads. I'm testing using my device which is a Samsung note 4 with a quad processor. Any insights will be highly welcome.

Thanks,

cwm

```
  public void testThreads() throws InterruptedException {
  startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            load1();
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            load2();
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  //  load1();
  //  load2();
    stopMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
    diffMilli = stopMilli - startMilli;
    startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public void load1() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(i = 0; i<100000; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }
}

public void load2() {
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(j = 100000; j<200000; j++){
        list2.add(j);
    }
}

  public void testThreads() throws InterruptedException {
  startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();

    load1();
    load2();
    stopMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
    diffMilli = stopMilli - startMilli;
    startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
public void load1() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(i = 0; i<100000; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }
}

public void load2() {
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(j = 100000; j<200000; j++){
        list2.add(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer. I tested few theories. Change `ArrayList` to `int[]`. It will improve performance drastically.

Comment: Most likely it's because you're not doing enough work to justify the use of threads. That is, it takes longer to start the thread than it does to add 100,000 items to a list. Change that to 10,000,000 items and run the test again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

General Guidelines:

It can be quite fiddly to increase application performance by use of threads; too few and you're not doing as well as you might, too many and the overhead of threads erodes the benefits gain from your program's concurrency.

To get it just right you have to setup as many threads as there are cores, and make sure you're program breaks down nicely to that many threads. That can be tricky to get right if you're allowing for the program being run on a wide range of hardware.

Thread pools were invented to help here. Broadly speaking, they have just the right number of threads for the hardware the program happens to be running on, and they let you submit lots of small concurrent tasks for execution without the overhead of setting up a new thread for each one. Thus your program runs well on a wide range of different hardware without having worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think OS memory managment is the problem in your case. In the first method you are adding 100000 elements simulteniously in each List. So both threads call resize operation at the same time which is probably locking memory while it finds new space for larger List, making other thread wait. In the second method 200000 elements are added sequentially, so no two simultenious resize operations occur and no memory is locked.

I ran tests for larger sets. Array was slightly faster than List implementation.

So here are the results with total 100000000 memory access operations

```
using array/arraylist

thread x4:    83 / 20000 ms  // each thread got 25000000 size chunk
thread x2:    75 / 22000 ms  // each thread got 50000000 size chunk
main thread:  146/ 25800 ms  // main thread processed all elements in one arraylist
```

But when I fill arraylist twice with `range/2` number of elements, time reduces from 25800 to 10100 ms.

```
int range = 100000000;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TEST m = new TEST();
    m.testThreads1(); // m.testThreads();
}

public void testThreads() throws InterruptedException {
    long startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            load1();
        }
    };
    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            load1();
        }
    };
    Thread t3 = new Thread() {...}
    Thread t4 = new Thread() {...}
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    long stopMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stopMilli - startMilli);
}

public void load1() {
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // int[] arr = new int[range];  // change size according to thread #
    for(int i = 0; i<range/2; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
        // arr[i]=i;
    }
}

public void testThreads1() throws InterruptedException {
    long startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /* 2 load1 call for `range/2` elements performes better than 1 call for `range` elements */
    load1();
    load1();
    long stopMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(stopMilli - startMilli);
}
```